# Why can I not catch this FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception, io

```
package test4;

import java.io.*;

public class Reader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(send("test.txt"));
    }

    public static BufferedReader send(String filename) {
        File file = null;
        FileReader filer = null;
        BufferedReader filed = null;

        try {
            file = new File(filename);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not find file!");
        }

        try {
            filer = new FileReader(file);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not initialize file reader!");
        }

        try {
            filed = new BufferedReader(filer);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not initialize buffered reader!");
        }

        return filed;
    }
}
```

The send method returns a null BufferedReader because the File can't be found. Eclipse just says there's a NullPointerException because of the print method, but when I remove all the try / catch statements, Eclipse says I need to write that the method throws either an IOException or FileNotFoundException, it also allows me to do this, and if I don't then it throws a FileNotFoundException. However, when I try to catch a FileNotFoundException for the File, Eclipse says that this is unreachable code? Basically this bit here:

```
    try {
        file = new File(filename);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not find file!");
    }
```

Why does Eclipse say that this code is unreachable when just removing the try / catch statements allows me to throw a FileNotFoundException?

Comment: `new File(filename)` won't throw a `FileNotFoundException`, you are allowed to create `File` objects with no existing physical file  (that's why the method `exists()`, exists).

Answer (score 4):

The File's contructor doesnt throw FileNotFoundException, you can see it here, at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-):

> public File(String pathname)
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting
>   the given pathname string into an abstract pathname. If the given
>   string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract
>   pathname.
>
> Parameters: pathname - A pathname string
>
> Throws:NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null

But the FileReader throws! Again, another [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader-java.io.File-)

> public FileReader(File file)
>              throws FileNotFoundException Creates a new FileReader, given the File to read from.
>
> Parameters: file - the File to read from
>
> Throws: FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a
>   directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot
>   be opened for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    file = new File(filename);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Could not find file!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `File(filename)` does not throw a `FileNotFoundException`, not even if the file does not exist, you can check that using `file.exists()`.

A FileNotFoundException will be thrown if you try to read a non-existing file.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run your program. The following pictures says that file isn't null

[image: debugger...]
[image]

`file` is created though the `filePath` is null. if you want to catch a `FileNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist, you can do something like this:

```
        if(!file.exists()){
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found");
        }
```